# Update job title and department for AD user account

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to write a Powershell script that accepts input for the username they want to change, then will accept input on what they'd like their job title and department changed to.

What is the syntax for changing job title and department within Active Directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Set-ADUser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617215.aspx) is what you're after:

```
Set-ADUser "User01" -Department "Sales" -Title "Manager"
```

You could also use [Read-Host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host) if you want to prompt for input.